# Create Column Based On Aggregation of Other Columns - Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, conditional-statements

I want to create a column whose values are equal to another column's when certain conditions are met. I want the column `first` to have the value of the column `share` when the columns `gender`, `week` and `type` are the same.
I have the following dataframe:

```
+------+----+----+-------------+-------------------+
|gender|week|type|        share|              units|
+------+----+----+-------------+-------------------+
|  Male|  37|Polo|         0.01|             1809.0| 
|  Male|  37|Polo|          0.1|             2327.0|
|  Male|  37|Polo|         0.15|             2982.0|
|  Male|  37|Polo|          0.2|             3558.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|         0.01|             1700.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|          0.1|             2245.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|         0.15|             2900.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|          0.2|             3477.0|
```

I want the output to be:

```
+------+----+----+-------------+-------------------+---------+
|gender|week|type|        share|              units|    first|
+------+----+----+-------------+-------------------+---------+
|  Male|  37|Polo|         0.01|             1809.0|   1809.0|
|  Male|  37|Polo|          0.1|             2327.0|   1809.0|
|  Male|  37|Polo|         0.15|             2982.0|   1809.0|
|  Male|  37|Polo|          0.2|             3558.0|   1809.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|         0.01|             1700.0|   1700.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|          0.1|             2245.0|   1700.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|         0.15|             2900.0|   1700.0|
|  Male|  38|Polo|          0.2|             3477.0|   1700.0|
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: In your example the output contains the values of the colum `units` not `share`

Comment: Also, it seems like (if I understood correctly) what you're asking is sensitive to the order of the rows. Have you implemented any ordering in your table on beforehand? If yes, please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer out so I will be posting it here.
I used a window function:

`m_window = Window.partitionBy(["gender","week","type"]).orderBy("share")`

Then I create a column using the function `first` and `over` window like this:

`df.withColumn("first", first("units").over(m_window))`